# aggregate inner query SQL optimization

Tags: sql, postgresql, metabase

I have 3 tables:

```
create table users
    (
        user_id varchar(50),
        birth_year int,
        country varchar(50)
    )


create table notifications 
    (
        status varchar(50), 
        user_id varchar(50), 
        created_date datetime
    )

create table transactions
    (
        transaction_id varchar(50),
        user_id varchar(50),
        created_date datetime
    )
```

What I want to do is to have for all users that received a notification, what is the difference in average transactions 7 days before the notification arrived vs. 7 days after the notification
arrived, by country and age group.

What I did is the following:

```
select q.country
, case when q.age <= 18 then '<= 18'
    when q.age <= 30 then '19 - 30'
    when q.age <= 45 then '31 - 45'
    when q.age <= 60 then '46 - 60'
    else '> 60' end as age_group
, AVG(q.prev_transactions*1.0) as avg_prev_transactions, AVG(q.post_transactions*1.0) as avg_post_transactions
from (
    select n.user_id, n.created_date, u.country, (2019 - u.birth_year) as age
    , count(distinct prev.transaction_id) as prev_transactions, count(distinct post.transaction_id) as post_transactions
    from notifications n
    left outer join transactions post on n.user_id = post.user_id and post.created_date > n.created_date and post.created_date < n.created_date + interval '7' day
    left outer join transactions prev on n.user_id = prev.user_id and prev.created_date < n.created_date and prev.created_date > n.created_date - interval '7' day
    left outer join users u on u.user_id = n.user_id
    where status = 'SENT'
    group by n.user_id, n.created_date, u.country, (2019 - u.birth_year)
    --order by n.user_id asc, n.created_date asc
    ) as q
group by q.country, case when q.age <= 18 then '<= 18'
    when q.age <= 30 then '19 - 30'
    when q.age <= 45 then '31 - 45'
    when q.age <= 60 then '46 - 60'
    else '> 60' end
```

I was wondering if there is a way to make it more efficient.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you multiplying by 1 here: `AVG(q.prev_transactions*1.0)`?

Comment: To force it to be a float (I am coming from a Transact-SQL background no much experience with Postgres)

Comment: Please `set track_io_timing=on` if possible, and then show `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for the query.  Also, run in the inner query "q" in isolation, and show it for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your two left joins on "transactions" are likely a problem.  If there are 30 prev transactions and 30 post transaction, then those two joins are essentially being cartesian joined together, creating 900 prev-post pairing.  These are then reduced back to 30 using DISTINCT. But you are doing work both to create, and then to remove, frivolous rows.

You could put them in a subselect each, instead of as joins.

```
select n.user_id, n.created_date, u.country, (2019 - u.birth_year) as age,
    (select count(*) from transactions post on n.user_id = post.user_id and post.created_date > n.created_date and post.created_date < n.created_date + interval '7' day) as post_transactions,
...
```

Also, why the left join against users?  What possibly meaningful output could be obtained for notifications with no user?

Comment: I used your suggestion in a dummy database and it shows a huge leap in term of the cost of the query (execution plan) compared to my initial query (23% vs 77%)

Yet it is still taking too much time to execute.

Comment: I replaced the outer join on the users' table by an inner join.